# Cannot access DLL inside Shared Project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms Shared project. 
I need to add a reference to System.Net.Http and after some research I found out it should be done via the regular `right click -> select assembly` (at every regular project), done that.
But now, if I go to any class on my shared project and try to use that DLL I can't (see image)

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

I've added the reference to every other project (iOS, Android and WinPhone) but can't access it on my Shared Project classes.

**EDIT**

After much try-and-error I figured it out...
I have 3 projects (iOS, Android AND WP8.1).

I was able to add System.Net.Http to iOS and Android projects but when I tried to do that at the WP project I got a message saying all needed DLLs were already in the SDK (how presumptuous!).

Anyway, I decided to unload WP project and it worked =/

So the problem now is: **How can I add that DLL to the WP project, since I want to support it, but I NEED System.Net.Http?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out.

The way I solved it was by unloading the WP project and reloading it. Perfect, it worked =)

After reloading the project I checked the `.NET for Windows Phone` reference and System.Net.Http is indeed there. Maybe this was just a cache thing, I don't know.

All I know is unloading the project and reloading it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can not add a reference to a project type of SharedProject. Instead you have to add this reference to the project you referenced the SharedProject to.

Consider the following:

You have a solution with a `console` project and a - lets call it `core` project - as a SharedProject.

Your `console` project references `core`. If you now want to use `System.Net.WebClient` you have to add the reference to System.Net to the `console` project.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was doing. I just re-read my question and saw that information wasn't clear. Just updated. I got it working, adding the reference doesn't "seem" to be the problem, I just can't use it.

Comment: I recently experienced the same behavior and could solve it be restarting Xamarin Studio or by closing the solution and re-open it.

I worked on a Mac at that time.

Comment: Thank you for sharing that, but I had tried all of that to no avail!